# Why is "Votes Cast" public?

Tags: discussion

I can see that "Votes Cast" is public. But why is it? At the most, I can say if the user downvotes or upvotes more (which *I* don't particularly think is informative, but that may be just me)

Is there any strong reason for it to be public?

Comment: During moderator elections it seems to be used as an indicator how well a user moderates, at least I saw snarky comments to candidates that had more up- than downvotes...which could be a reason to keep this private overall...

Comment: @rene that's the exact reason why I opened this question up, but didn't posted it exactly that way though

Answer (score 26):

Your profile page is, and always will be an indication of how you participate in various areas of the site. Everything that users can do, including moderators, is quite transparent - and that is very much by design. Voting is *essential* to the upkeep of the site, hence we show it.

*How* you vote is strictly up to you and kept private except for the aggregate counts, even if you elect *not* to vote. It's your preference. Some designs [currently in the works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) hope to make all of the information on your profile page (including voting) a bit more meaningful with context, but we'll always show it.

It's there to remind you that you *can* vote, and for you to keep track of how often you vote - users tend to spend quite a bit of time on their profile pages. However, it's also an artifact of *how* you participate, hence public, just like every other way that you can participate that doesn't imply confidentiality (e.g. flagging).

With very few exceptions, *everything* you do on the site is public, that's how it was designed.